# jQuery change countup method to countdown on Circle Bars Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this [plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Progress-Bar-Countdown-Timer-jQuery-circlebars/) to add countdown.

This working good only for count up not for countdown.

My question, is there any way to make the seconds number to be countdown not count up?

```js
$("#circle-1").Circlebar({
    maxValue: 20,
    fontSize: "14px"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Progress-Bar-Countdown-Timer-jQuery-circlebars/assets/circle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Progress-Bar-Countdown-Timer-jQuery-circlebars/assets/demo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Progress-Bar-Countdown-Timer-jQuery-circlebars/assets/skins/yellowcircle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Progress-Bar-Countdown-Timer-jQuery-circlebars/assets/circle.js"></script>

<div id="circle-1" data-circle-dialWidth=10 data-circle-skin="yellow">
    <div class="loader-bg">
        <div class="text">00:00:00</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This [library](https://github.com/itaditya/circlebars) does not natively support countdown functionality, only timers. You would need to write this logic yourself, or find an alternative library which does what you need

Comment: Check this code https://jsfiddle.net/Divyanshi88_/1rLnshmy/1/

Comment: Hi, is there any possible to modify the current plugin to be countdown type?

Comment: *is it possible to modify the plugin* - sure, go for it, or ask the original developer to add that feature.  Otherwise, write your own or find a different plugin.

Comment: Plugin site: https://github.com/itaditya/circlebars

Comment: Looks like you can set the type to `manual` and update the values yourself

Comment: However, it turns out it's not a very well written plugin and doesn't follow standard jquery plugin rules (so not really a "plugin") - doesn't return something you can work with and the setValue method is private.    Just edit the plugin to do what you want.